# After insert trigger doesn't work when using Inserted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger on my `Employees` table that should not allow the insertion of a new employee that has a hire date that is older than the hire date of his boss

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ename] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [IsMarried] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Birthdate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [HireDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [NationalityID] [int] NULL,
    [BossID] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ()
)
```

And here's the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig_04]
ON [dbo].[Employees]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT INSERTED.HireDate FROM INSERTED WHERE BossID <> EID) < 
        (SELECT Employees.HireDate FROM Employees 
         WHERE EID IN (SELECT Employees.BossID FROM Employees WHERE BossID <> EID)))
        ROLLBACK
END
```

It executes normally (no errors) but it just doesn't work, but when I was using the employees table in the subquery instead of the inserted table, it was working normally. Does anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write triggers in SQL Server to handle the fact that `INSERTED` could contain multiple records. You cannot assume it will only be a single record. I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
if exists (
  select 1
  from Inserted I
  where I.BossID <> I.EID
  and I.HireDate < (select E.HireDate from Employees E where E.EID = I.BossID)
) begin
    ROLLBACK;
end
```

Comment: @SarahSiblini - did this help?